# Casting inside JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

The Item entity has extended to another Entity Amp which has a property of Vmp. How can I query Vmp in side a Jpql. Can I do casting inside Jpql?

I used Jpql without casting like this.

```
select i from Stock i where i.stock >:s and i.department=:d and i.itemBatch.item.vmp=:vmp order by i.itemBatch.item.name
```

The ItemBatch has a property of Item class, but I am only retracting Amp entities, which extends Item class. Only Amp has a property of Vmp. So the above Jpql gives following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [select i from Stock i where i.stock >:s and i.department=:d and i.itemBatch.item.vmp=:vmp order by i.itemBatch.item.name]. 
[85, 105] The state field path 'i.itemBatch.item.vmp' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

Can I cast inside Jpql like below ot is there any other workaround?

```
select i from Stock i where i.stock >:s and i.department=:d and  Atm(i.itemBatch.item).vmp=:vmp order by i.itemBatch.item.name
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the method, have to use treat instead of cast. This is the Jpql

```
jpql = "select i from Stock i join treat(i.itemBatch.item as Amp) amp where i.stock >:s and i.department=:d and amp.vmp=:vmp order by i.itemBatch.item.name";
```